# References in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way in Excel 365 to reference a cell in a formula and lock it so that if I drag the referenced cell it does not change the cell reference in the formula?

I am using a spreadsheet to build a custom deck of cards, the last column uses `=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, G2, A2)`. The problem is that if I drag the first card data down to G8 and A8 the last column's formula will change automatically to `=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, G8, A8)`. I want the last column's formula to remain referenced to G2 and A2 even when I move the data and even an absolute reference will change when I move the data.

If I fill in the form normally then H displays correctly.
[image: If I fill in the form normally then H displays correctly.]

If I want to rearrange my cards in a different order and drag the data in `A4:G4` to `A8:G8` then the formula in `H4` will change to displaying the text in `G8` and `A8` instead of remaining to display the original text in row 2 and the formula in row 8 is now errored.
[image: If I want to rearrange my cards in a different order and drag the data in A4:G4 to A8:G8 then the formula in H2 will change to displaying the text in G8 and A8 instead of remaining to display the original text in row 2 and the formula in row 8 is now errored]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps convert your data to a table using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and then modify your formula to the following:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,[@Name],[@['# In Deck]])
```

[image]

Comment: I get an error "The syntax of this name isn't correct." and it then highlights the [@Name] part of the function.

Comment: Did you convert your data to a table?

Comment: Yes, it now has the dropdown menu.

Comment: I added a picture of the error, I can't figure out how to use the formula the way you have provided it.

Comment: As regards your last edit - select *all* of the data in columns A - H and format it as a table. As is, you have two separate tables - one in column A and one in column H. Your screenshot should look like mine.